# Custom ListView not working with adapter(android)

Tags: android

I have three files the Word Adapter.java which is a subclass of the Array adapter and list_item.xml which is my list item layout and word_list.java which is where my list is created and an adapter is set for it and finally word_list.xml which is where the list is inflated.I copied the AndroidFlavourAdapter code from github and modified it to suit my adapter.Please help,Im new to android, I've gone over it over and over and even checked different post on this site with different suggestions but non is working, the app only crashes when I click on word_list.xml activity which is where the list is to be displayed. And sorry for this unorganised post that i've got, also new to stackoverflow. Thank you.

```html
public class WordAdapter extends ArrayAdapter<Words> {


    /**
     * This is a custom constructor (it doesn't mirror a superclass constructor).
     * The context is used to inflate the layout file, and the list is the data we want
     * to populate into the lists.
     *
     * @param context        The current context. Used to inflate the layout file.
     * @param currentWord A List of both english and hausa objects to display in a list
     */

    public WordAdapter(Activity context, ArrayList<Words> currentWord) {
        // Here, we initialize the ArrayAdapter's internal storage for the context and the list.
        // the second argument is used when the ArrayAdapter is populating a single TextView.
        // Because this is a custom adapter for two TextViews and an ImageView, the adapter is not
        // going to use this second argument, so it can be any value. Here, we used 0.
        super(context, 0 , currentWord);
    }



    @NonNull
    /**
     * Provides a view for an AdapterView (ListView, GridView, etc.)
     *
     * @param position The position in the list of data that should be displayed in the
     *                 list item view.
     * @param convertView The recycled view to populate.
     * @param parent The parent ViewGroup that is used for inflation.
     * @return The View for the position in the AdapterView.
     */
    @Override
    public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {
        // Check if the existing view is being reused, otherwise inflate the view


        View listItemView = convertView;
        if(listItemView == null) {

            listItemView = LayoutInflater.from(getContext()).inflate(R.layout.word_list,parent,false);
        }



        // Get the {@link word} object located at this position in the list
        Words currentWord = getItem(position);

        // Find the TextView in the list_item.xml layout with the ID version_name
        TextView hausaTextView = (TextView) listItemView.findViewById(R.id.haus_view);
        // Find the TextView in the list_item.xml layout with the ID version_number
        TextView englishTextView = (TextView) listItemView.findViewById(R.id.englis_view);
        // Get the version name from the current AndroidFlavor object and
        // set this text on the name TextView
        hausaTextView.setText(currentWord.getHausa());

        // Get the version number from the current AndroidFlavor object and
        // set this text on the number TextView
        englishTextView.setText(currentWord.getDefault());


        // Return the whole list item layout (containing 2 TextViews and an ImageView)
        // so that it can be shown in the ListView
        return listItemView;
    }
}
```

```html
public class word_list extends AppCompatActivity {

    // list of words for both english and hausa
    ArrayList<Words> hausaList = new ArrayList<Words>();

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.word_list);
        // add words to the arrayList object hausaList with constructor that has both english and hausa words as parameters
        hausaList.add(new Words("one", "daya"));
        hausaList.add(new Words("two", "biyu"));
        hausaList.add(new Words("three", "uku"));
        hausaList.add(new Words("four", "hudu"));
        hausaList.add(new Words("five", "biyar"));
        hausaList.add(new Words("six", "shida"));
        hausaList.add(new Words("seven", "bakwai"));
        hausaList.add(new Words("eight", "takwas"));
        hausaList.add(new Words("nine", "tara"));
        hausaList.add(new Words("ten", "goma"));
        hausaList.add(new Words("eleven", "sha daya"));
        hausaList.add(new Words("twelve", "sha biyu"));

        ListAdapter myAdapter = new WordAdapter(this, hausaList);
        ListView myListView = (ListView) findViewById(R.id.rootView);
        myListView.setAdapter(myAdapter);

    }
}
```

```html
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:id="@+id/list_itemz"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:orientation="vertical"
    android:padding="16dp">


    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/haus_view"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        tools:text="daya" />

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/englis_view"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        tools:text="one" />

</LinearLayout>
```

```html
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<ListView xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:orientation="vertical"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:paddingTop="16dp"
    android:paddingBottom="16dp"
    android:paddingRight="16dp"
    android:paddingLeft="16dp"
    android:id="@+id/rootView"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    />
```

Comment: What error does it give you? Put the log trace please

Comment: Your ListView xml looks awkward.

Comment: @faisalsaah: post your error

Comment: the only error it says on the device is unfurtunately stoped working and when I tried to put a ListView on the list_itemz layout it gives addView(View, LayoutParams) is not supported in AdapterView

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In your getView method of the WordAdapter class you actually need to **inflate the xml file containing the layout used for each row** in your list.

Try to change this line :

```
listItemView = LayoutInflater.from(getContext()).inflate(R.layout.word_list,parent,false);
```

With :

```
listItemView = LayoutInflater.from(getContext()).inflate(R.layout.list_item,parent,false);
```

Comment: god, it worked. cant tell you how happy I am, it has been driving me crazy.